# percentual width with position:absolute

Tags: css, wordpress, width, css-position, percentage

I have a problem with a width on one of my divs. It had a width of 100% relative to my content box (About 800 px in fullscreen). However, when I changed the position to absolute, the width became 1440px (My screen size). Is there a workaround for this problem?

I cant send the whole code, but the page can be seen here:

http://stilius.se/wilink/store/products/category/stockholm_nacka_tullen_ica/?cat=42

Thanks in advance!

/Johannes Persson, Stilius

Answer (score 0):

what about if you put the following on #maindesc

```
position:relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of a `position: absolute;` element will be relative to the *closest positioned  ancestor*. So if you want 100% to be 100% of some ancestor element, give that ancestor `position: relative;`

In your case, somethig like this should do the trick;

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
}
```

An element is considered to be *positioned* if it has a `position` value other than `static` (default)